# Invisible ActionBar Search Icon

Tags: android

So i set the theme as `"android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"`, and i've added a search icon  from holo.dark. However, it's impossible(nearly) to see this icon. Anyway to make it 'whiter'?

[image: App]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/search_actionbar"/>


</menu>
```

am also using same theme for me action bar search icon showing white color only..

Comment: Perfect. This worked. Is the 3rd line necessary? What does it do?

Comment: android having predefined searchView class ,just refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html